# I want to detect if a user types a certain string into a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox that looks like this

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactAddress, new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "75" })%>
```

in my javascript i have this

```
   $('.save_button_cont').click(function (e) {


        var addr1 = $('#ContactAddress').val();

        if(addr1.indexOf("box") > -1) {
            alert("HEY NO P.O. BOXES ALLOWED ");
        }

            document.forms[0].submit();
        });
```

i was hoping that this would pop up the alert before posting if the user had 'box' in the textbox. it doesnt work though.

I want to show an alert if the user enters the string 'box' in their address (the textbox).

EDIT: on the submit i am going to use a confirm box to verify that the user wants to continue. thanks for the help

Comment: Please don't change your question to a different question after it's been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$("#textboxid").blur(function(){
if( $("#textboxid").val() == "box"){
alert("box typed!");
}
});
```

this will make your life easy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('.save_button_cont').click(function (e) {
      var addr1 = $('#ContactAddress').val();
            if(addr1.indexOf("box") > -1) {
                alert("blah");
            }else {
                alert('Bleh');
            }
            alert("TEST");

            $('form').eq(0).submit();
        });
```

Comment: I think the way i am grabbing the value of the textbox might be wrong. i am not getting any alerts :/

Comment: Also, are you sure that the class of your save button is `save_button_cont`? If you're not getting any alerts at all, the code may not be running. Is your form submitting?

Comment: ok i figured something out. this code works and realizes when 'box' is  in the textbox.  check original post plz. thank you for the replies so far

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.save_button_cont').click(function (e) {
    var addr1 = $('#ContactAddress').val();
    if (addr1.indexOf("box") > -1) alert("blah");
    else alert('Bleh');
    $('#formID').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if(~addr1.indexOf("box")) {...} else {...}
```

Try

```
if(addr1 === "box") {...} else {...}
```

Comment: That won't work if it's `this is a test box`, which it sounds like he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to test the string for the occurrence of "box". This will allow you to do a case-insensitive search:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $('#test').val();
    if (/box/i.test(input)) {
        alert("bad");
    } else {
        alert("good");
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

You should also put the "submit" function in your "else" statement so the form only submits on validation success.

NOTE: this could cause unwanted issues if the user happens to live on "box street".